# three.js отображение текстур при анимации в json модели

Tags: three.js, blender

Никак не могу заставить отображаться текстуры в json модели, экспортированной из блендера.

У меня есть стандартный блендоровский куб. При помощи анимации заставил его ползать. Без скелета. Просто перемещение по двум ключевым кадрам. Залил текстуру, через панель Texture (Type Image or Movie) - просто картинку. И выгрузил всё в JSON.
Получилось так:

```
{
    "materials":[{
        "blending":1,
        "DbgColor":15658734,
        "DbgName":"Material.001",
        "depthTest":true,
        "DbgIndex":0,
        "specularCoef":50,
        "wireframe":false,
        "shading":"phong",
        "depthWrite":true,
        "mapDiffuseWrap":["repeat","repeat"],
        "transparent":false,
        "visible":true,
        "colorEmissive":[0,0,0],
        "mapDiffuseRepeat":[1,1],
        "colorSpecular":[0.005668,0.007784,0.5],
        "colorDiffuse":[0.03412,0.048951,0.757333],
        "opacity":1,
        "mapDiffuseAnisotropy":1,
        "doubleSided":false,
        "mapDiffuse":"HUESeR6h7C4.jpg"
    }],
"morphTargets":[{
        "name":"animation_000000",
        "vertices":[1.37341,-1.02254,1.35629,1.37341,0.977456,1.35629,1.37341,-1.02254,-0.643712,1.37341,0.977455,-0.643712,3.37341,-1.02254,1.35629,3.37341,0.977456,1.35629,3.37341,-1.02254,-0.643712,3.37341,0.977455,-0.643712]
    }, ... ],
   "vertices":[1.37979,-1.01632,1.3379,1.37979,0.983676,1.3379,1.37979,-1.01632,-0.662102,1.37979,0.983676,-0.662102,3.37979,-1.01632,1.3379,3.37979,0.983676,1.3379,3.37979,-1.01632,-0.662102,3.37979,0.983676,-0.662102],
    "uvs":[],
    "bones":[],
    "influencesPerVertex":2,
    "animations":[],
    "skinWeights":[],
    "skinIndices":[],
    "normals":[-1,0,0,0,-0,-1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,-1,0,0,1,-0],
    "faces":[35,0,1,3,2,0,0,0,0,0,35,2,3,7,6,0,1,1,1,1,35,6,7,5,4,0,2,2,2,2,35,1,0,4,5,0,3,3,3,3,35,4,0,2,6,0,4,4,4,4,35,7,3,1,5,0,5,5,5,5],
    "metadata":{
        "type":"Geometry",
        "materials":1,
        "morphTargets":250,
        "vertices":8,
        "uvs":0,
        "bones":0,
        "version":3,
        "generator":"io_three",
        "normals":6,
        "faces":6
    }
}
```

---

загрузил полученный JSON и картинку с текстурой и анимацией в three.js через JSONloader

```
let mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer( scene );
let clock  = new THREE.Clock();

jsonLoader.load("./objects/untitled.json",
    function( geometry, materials ) {
        var material = materials[0];
        material.morphTargets = true;
        let mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material)
        mesh.scale.set(5,5,5)
        mesh.position.set(0,140,0)
        scene.add(mesh);
        mixer.clipAction( geometry.animations[ 0 ], mesh ).setDuration( 3 ).play();
    }
)
```

этот код проигрывает анимацию, но не отображает текстуру.
Показывает лишь материал, который был задан в блендере до текстурирования.
[image: синий куб без текстур]
т.е. вот этот синий куб - анимированная модель. И она двигается как положено, но та картинка, которая на него была наложена в блендере при текстурировании не отображается в THREE.js. Отображается лишь блендеровский материал. Стоит поменять при экспорте цвет материала на красный, и куб становится красным, а картинки всё равно нет. Консоль по этому поводу ничего не пишет.
Большиниство способов решения написаны под устарвшие методы. Убил уже 2 дня, перепробовал всё что только можно.
Я не понимаю на каком этапе у меня ошибки. При экспорте модели, или при работе с Three.js?
Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Путь прописан правильно? Я смотрю, моделька находится в папке objects, а где картинка?

Comment: картинка лежит там же. в objects.
Если её убрать или переименовать, то консоль выводит ошибку 404 - не удаётся загрузить изображение по адресу localhost:3333/objects/HUESeR6h7C4.jpg
Что уже совсем сбивает с толку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё получилось.
Для заливки текстур воспользовался этим видео - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1AbJ0V5kg5Q
до этого не применял UV, видимо причина была в этом

Галочки при экспорте текстурированной анимации проставил так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]